# groupBy filtered column

Tags: dataframe, julia

We have a data frame containing weather data.
**`datetime` - `value`**

```
01.01.2010 - 20  
02.01.2010 - 22
```

We now want to group by the **year** and the **day**.
Our current code is
`grouped = by(dataFrame, :datetime, df -> nrow(df))`
We want something like `grouped = by(dataFrame, Date.Year(:datetime), df -> nrow(df))`

Does anyone know how to call a function to a column before grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not able to do this and have to create a new column first. The reason is that grouping column then must appear in `GroupedDataFrame` object that is created by `groupby` (so they have to be materialized).

Threfore you should do something like (I understand you want to drop month from grouping - right?):

```
dataFrame.dy = Date.Year(dataFrame.datetime)
dataFrame.dd = Date.Day(dataFrame.datetime)
grouped = by(dataFrame, [:dy, :dd], :datetime, nrow)
```

Now, to show you the reason why this is needed call:

```
groupby(dataFrame, [:dy, :dd])
```

and you will see that you have `:dy` and `:dd` columns in `SubDataFrame`s produced by indexing the result of this call, so we need to materialize them.